# Postgresql: pg_dump what are [large objects]

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I was trying to do a backup using pg_dump.
There is an option keep me wondering.

According to `pg_dump  --help`

```
 -b, --blobs                  include large objects in dump
```

I try looking for blobs, but only got info regarding BYTEA

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-binary.html

so what are **`large objects`** ?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html

Thanks this answer my question.

I just got a negative vote for my question.
In my defense i search for `posgres BLOB` and only find info about the `BYTEA` column, but not about the definition of `LARGE OBJECT`